# pthread in a class

Tags: c++, class, function, pthreads, member

Hey everyone, considering the following code (compiled with `g++ -lpthread thread_test.cpp`) how can I know what number thread I am in from inside "thread_function"? And let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Thanks!

thread_test.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class A { 
   public:
      A();
      void run();

   private:
      static void* thread_function( void *ptr );
      pthread_t m_thread1, m_thread2;

      static int m_global;
};

int A::m_global = 0;

A::A() {
   int ret1 = pthread_create( &m_thread1, NULL, &A::thread_function, this );
   int ret2 = pthread_create( &m_thread2, NULL, &A::thread_function, this );
}

void A::run() {
   while ( 1 ) { 
      printf( "parent incrementing...\n" );
      m_global++;
      sleep( 2 );
   }   
}

void* A::thread_function( void *ptr ) { 
   printf( "I'm thread ?\n" );

   while ( 1 ) { 
      printf("thread global: %d\n", m_global );
      sleep( 1 );
   }   
}

int main() {
   A a;
   a.run();

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pthread_self() function.

Comment: ok i see that now... should i use something like pthread_key_create to store some kind of thread specific data in it to identify whether it is thread 1 or 2 then? I'm trying to figure out if pthread_key_create is really what I want...

Comment: You could use thread specific variable but I don't think it's necessary. Just call pthread_self() whenever you want to use current thread number.

Answer (score 1):

Well i figured out I could do this, but I'm not sure if making the pthread_t variables static is the best thing to do. Opinions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class A { 
   public:
      A();
      void run();

   private:
      static void* thread_function( void *ptr );
      static pthread_t m_thread1, m_thread2;

      static int m_global;
};

int A::m_global = 0;
pthread_t A::m_thread1 = 0;
pthread_t A::m_thread2 = 0;

A::A() {
   int ret1 = pthread_create( &m_thread1, NULL, &A::thread_function, this );
   int ret2 = pthread_create( &m_thread2, NULL, &A::thread_function, this );
}

void A::run() {
   while ( 1 ) { 
      printf( "parent incrementing...\n" );
      m_global++;
      sleep( 2 );
   }   
}

void* A::thread_function( void *ptr ) { 
    int thread_num = 0;
    if ( pthread_self() == m_thread1 ) {
        thread_num = 1;
    } else {
        thread_num = 2;
    }

    printf( "I'm thread %d\n", thread_num );

    while ( 1 ) { 
        printf("thread %d global: %d\n", thread_num, m_global );
        sleep( 1 );
    }   
}

int main() {
   A a;
   a.run();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot compare pthread_t's that way. You *must* use pthread_equal.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer depends heavily on why you need this information. If the two threads are doing different things, why do they have the same start function?

One simple fix is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class A { 
   public:
      A();
      void run();

   private:
      static void* thread_function( void *ptr, int which );
      static void* thread_function_1( void *ptr );
      static void* thread_function_2( void *ptr );
      pthread_t m_thread1, m_thread2;

      static int m_global;
};

int A::m_global = 0;

A::A() {
   int ret1 = pthread_create( &m_thread1, NULL, &A::thread_function_1, this );
   int ret2 = pthread_create( &m_thread2, NULL, &A::thread_function_2, this );
}

void A::run() {
   while ( 1 ) { 
      printf( "parent incrementing...\n" );
      m_global++;
      sleep( 2 );
   }   
}

void* A::thread_function_1( void *ptr ) { thread_function(ptr, 1); }
void* A::thread_function_2( void *ptr ) { thread_function(ptr, 2); }

void* A::thread_function( void *ptr, int which ) { 
   printf( "I'm thread %d\n", which );

   while ( 1 ) { 
      printf("thread global: %d\n", m_global );
      sleep( 1 );
   }   
}

int main() {
   A a;
   a.run();

   return 0;
}
```

If you have more than 2 threads, you can use another approach. Create a structure that holds all the information the thread needs, including the `this` pointer and which thread it is. Allocate a structure of that type, stuff it with everything the thread needs and pass that to the thread through the `pthread_create` function instead of just the `this` pointer.